# Dialog doesn't properly close when initiated by focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I wish to open a dialog when an input is focused upon.  It used to work perfectly, but I must have upgraded jQuery and/or jQueryUI, and now FF doesn't remove the modal and IE doesn't even close the dialog box.  Please see http://jsbin.com/EdupOgE/2/ for a live example.  As shown in my example, it does work fine using click, but not focus.  Why is this happening and how do I fix it?  Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready( function() {

                $("#id_focus").focus(function(){$("#dialog").dialog("open");});
                $("#id_click").click(function(){$("#dialog").dialog("open");});

                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    modal       : true,
                    buttons     : [{text    : 'CANCEL',click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}}]    
                });

        });</script>

    </head>

    <body>
        None:  <input type="text" value="" />
        Click: <input id="id_click" readonly="readonly" value="PORTLAND OR 97232" />
        Focus: <input id="id_focus" readonly="readonly" value="PORTLAND OR 97232" />
        <div id="dialog" title="Title"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add `$("#id_focus").blur();` to the focus function like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHrkL/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#id_focus").focus(function () {
        $("#id_focus").blur(); // Important bit
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
    $("#id_click").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [{
            text: 'CANCEL',
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });

});
```

From [the API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/):

> ## Focus
>
> Upon opening a dialog, focus is automatically moved to the first item
>   that matches the following:
>
> 1. The first element within the dialog with the autofocus attribute
> 2. The first :tabbable element within the dialog's content
> 3. The first :tabbable element within the dialog's buttonpane
> 4. The dialog's close button
> 5. The dialog itself
>
> While open, the dialog widget ensures that tabbing cycles focus
>   between elements within the dialog itself, not elements outside of it.
>   Modal dialogs additionally prevent mouse users from clicking on
>   elements outside of the dialog.
>
> **Upon closing a dialog, focus is automatically returned to the element
>   that had focus when the dialog was opened.**

<sup>emphasis on that last bit is mine</sup>

So if focus is returned to `#id_focus` after the dialog is closed it should be trying to reopen the dialog immediately after it's been closed... I imagine that no good can come from this circular functionality and it's likely the cause of your troubles...

Comment: Thanks apaul,  You solution seems to work. It also seems like `$("#id_focus").blur();` can be replaced with `this.blur();`.  I was a little surprised that I didn't need to use `$(this).blur();` as I didn't think `this` was an jQuery object in the given context.  I was planning on asking why blur was needed, but I see you just edited your post, so probably I should read it first!

Comment: @user1032531 6 vs half dozen... `$(this).blur(); this.blur(); $("#id_focus").blur();` they should all work equally well, I doubt there's enough of a performance difference to really matter.

Comment: @user1032531 does the explanation in the edit make sense to you?

Comment: Yes it does, Thank you. I will be selecting this as a great answer (as well as giving it +1).  No, I don't think they are all the same as `this.blur()` is not a jQuery function but a browser function and will not work with Opera (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_blur.asp).  I think `$(this)` is a little better that `$('#id_focus')` from a maintainability.   So, is it fair to say that the model never goes away, but just remains unfocused when the dialog is closed?  Regardless, thank you for your help!

Comment: @user1032531 I believe the dialog is just hidden using `.hide()` giving it an inline style of `display:none;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#id_focus").onfocus(function () {   
        $("#id_focus").blur();    
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });

});
```